# Help finding what formula can solve this problem

Tags: physics, advice

I am trying to calculate out something, but no matter how much I try I keep running into issues, such as making formulae that are infinitely recursive without finding an answer.

So I am trying to calculate out the velocity that an object would be at, given drag forces, if it somehow changes mass. I know how to find the velocity ignoring Drag, given Conservation of Momentum.

$m_1v_1 = \frac{1}{am_1v_1}$

$v_2 = v_1 * a$

Kinetic energy would be,

$\frac{(mv_1^2 * a)}{2}$

But I can not find a formula wherein this takes into account how such an object, while speeding up, is also slowed down by drag. To find the true velocity that it would be made to reach.

Note, this is not about a falling object, I know how to do that. This is about an object in a horizontal direction. Furthermore, I know this is better suited towards physics stack exchange, but they are both very picky with what is asked there, and I also feel that since this is mainly based on mathematics, it is better here.

This has been driving me insane and help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is not enough information here to understand your question. For example, it is impossible to answer this question without having a formula for the drag force in question. Also, is the mass of the object changing instantaneously? Or slowly over time? You should give an actual example of the kind of problem you'd like to solve.

Comment: maybe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation) could help

Answer (score 1):

Let $m$ be the mass of the object at time $t$, $v$ be the velocity at time $t$, $F_D$ be the size of the drag force at time $t$. These are all functions of $t$.

Since the only force exerted to the object is drag, we have the following by Newton's second law of motion:

$$\frac{d(mv)}{dt}=-F_D$$
$$\implies v\frac{dm}{dt}+m\frac{dv}{dt}=-F_D$$

Let $\frac{dm}{dt}/m=r$. If we want to find $v$:

$$\frac{dv}{dt}+rv=\frac{-F_D}{m}$$

Apply the formula of the solution to a linear differential equation.

$$v=e^{-\int rdt}\bigg(\int\frac{-F_D}{m}e^{\int rdt}dt \;+C \bigg)$$

All the indefinite integrals have no integration constant and $C$ is a constant. We can use this to find the velocity when $m$ decreased to $\frac{1}{a}m$. Notice the result would be different when how $m$ changes is different.

Comment: Thank you, I will try to see if this does as I am looking for.

Comment: By the way, where did this problem come from? @Zoey

Comment: I have trouble calculating this out on a computer. Symbolab says that nesting the indefinite integrals is invalid. Also, another question, how would I enter into r the desired mass change, as in, what format does it take. What input would get out a change in mass wherein one reduces their mass to 75%.                                                                                                Also, where do I enter the original velocity, as the starting velocity is rather important to the problem. As it effects the final velocity.

Comment: Both the current momentum and kinetic energy (therefore initial velocity), and the change in mass, are important to the final results. Momentum is mv, and while it is initially conserved, it is later reduced depending on the drag. | So essentially, it needs to take in the original velocity and mass, and change the velocity depending upon the changed mass.

Comment: Think I found it out, just without taking into account the slower change in mass. So it treats it as instant.

Comment: @Zoey If you're going to calculate using a computer, you should input the differential equation (third equation). The last equation is for calculating by hand.

Comment: Using Symbolab, you have to replace $v$ with $y$ because otherwise Symbolab won't recognize it as a differential equation. Also, use $y'$ instead of $dy/dt$.

Comment: The result should be $y=$ some function of $t$ and you'll find $c_1$ in it. In this function, substitute $t=0$ and adjust $c_1$ so that $y$ would be the initial velocity that you want.

Comment: @Zoey About the mass. You can't just determine the final velocity without knowing **how** the mass has changed over time. Remember $m$ was a function of $t$, so if you want it to decrease linearly, use $m=m_0 - kt$, if exponentially, $m=m_0 e^{-kt}$. $m_0$ is the initial mass; $k$ is the speed of decrease. Take the derivative of $m$ and divide it by $m$, this is $r$, which is also a function of $t$. When you've done all this, replace  $m$ and $r$ with what you've got (as functions of $t$), and run the differential equation on Symbolab.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134304/discussion-between-zoey-and-jjm336).